# Manual wrapping with pre

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a page to display email messages.  I have something like this in a `pre` with `white-space: pre`:

```
>> Donec tincidunt lobortis orci, a cursus dui ullamcorper
>> vel. Praesent vel enim et lectus aliquet laoreet. In tempus
>> sodales.
```

Now, when the screen-y is too small and it overflows, I don't want to use `overflow: auto`. Instead, I want it to wrap automatically like this:

```
>> Donec tincidunt lobortis orci, a cursus
>> dui ullamcorper vel. Praesent vel enim
>> et lectus aliquet laoreet. In tempus
>> sodales.
```

I wouldn't mind using `:before` if I were able to select the text in the page and copy it to an email message as-it-is.

Okay, let's first try to solve a simpler version of the problem: let's say there is no ">> " prefix in front of each line.  I can use `white-space: normal`, but when I copy out the text, I get one line without line-breaks and this is undesirable.  So, how do I get my browser to wrap text without losing the ability to copy it out with line-breaks as it is displayed?

Comment: You can't, at least not with only HTML/CSS.  Either the newline is there or it isn't.  You can't copy something that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
pre {
 white-space: pre-wrap;      
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer */
}
```

But it takes care of the >> as a bullet...
Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/M4L8h/)